# How to enable WEBGL in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webgl

I've read several posts explaining that I should simply be adding the following lines to my `CDVViewController.m Class`.

```
    id webDocumentView = [self.webView performSelector:@selector(_browserView)];
    id backingWebView = [webDocumentView performSelector:@selector(webView)];
    [backingWebView _setWebGLEnabled:YES]; // throws ERROR
```

Error message `"No known instance method for selector "_setWebGLEnabled:YES:"` shows up and does not let me compile the project.

I'm using iOS SDK 6.1 and Cordova 2.6.0

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same thing! This guy seems to have found a workaround with the iAd toolset and a ton of hackery:
http://atnan.com/blog/2011/11/03/enabling-and-using-webgl-on-ios

Your method seems more along the lines of what I'm trying to do, however. If I can get it to work I'll post an update.